# PHP JOIN Query adjustment for status on product but cannot work out

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

my queries all work great which is good but it is pulling the min and max prices for all products and I only want to pull the data for products that have a status of "a"

I have the condition within the queries, but don't think it's correct. The table *cscart_product_prices* does not have status only *cscart_products* so need to some how add the condition in to just pass back status a for what prices are pulled back if that makes sense?

```
$proMaxPrice = db_get_row("select max(price) as mianprice FROM cscart_product_prices as cpp LEFT JOIN cscart_products_categories as cpc on cpc.product_id=cpp.product_id LEFT JOIN cscart_products AS cp ON cpc.product_id = cp.product_id where cpc.category_id ='".$key."' AND cp.status='A' ");
$proMinPrice = db_get_row("select min(price) as mianprice FROM cscart_product_prices as cpp LEFT JOIN cscart_products_categories as cpc on cpc.product_id=cpp.product_id LEFT JOIN cscart_products AS cp ON cpc.product_id = cp.product_id where cpc.category_id ='".$key."' AND cp.status='A' ");
```

It more or less brings back **min** and **max** price for products within the categories, but regardless of what status the products have, "A" is active, "D" is disabled and "H" is hidden... its getting price for all and I just need for products that are "A" active.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas? sorry for asking again, only its 1:30am here and need to resolve tonight and also push live once fixed so cant sleep until i fix it and so far having no luck at all lol

Answer (score 0):

Without table definitions and some sample data is not easy to figure out what the expected query is.

However, have you thought about using inner joins instead of left joins?
Also, I would rewrite the query like this:

```
select max(price) as mianprice 
FROM cscart_product_prices as cpp 
LEFT JOIN cscart_products_categories as cpc on cpc.product_id=cpp.product_id AND 
  cpc.category_id ='".$key."'
LEFT JOIN cscart_products AS cp ON cpc.product_id = cp.product_id AND cp.status='A'
```

Comment: I did try in phpmyadmin with setting the category ID and min and max returned 199 which was right, just when in production on the site does not which is weird but as you say would rather use inner joins so let me give that a go now and ill let you know...

Comment: getting: Unknown column 'cp.status' in 'on clause' (1054)select min(price) as mianprice           FROM cscart_product_prices as cpp           LEFT JOIN cscart_products_categories as cpc on cpc.product_id=cpp.product_id AND             cpc.category_id ='7' AND cp.status='A'

Comment: think only cscart_products has status if that helps

Comment: Apologies I didn't see status belonged to cscart_products. try the updated query. But again, if you don't need LEFT JOINs I would just do inner JOINs.

Comment: weird, everything coming back as 0.50 - $699 for everything so worse than it was  haha before was pulling right min and max prices but just needed to only for products with status A - im new to PHP and MySQL and someone else done this so trying to fix as only one available to do the release tonight.